# How to send HDMI-CEC commands from Amlogic 905x board to the TV using sysfs

Tags: android, hdmi, sysfs, hdmi-cec

I want to send raw HDMI-CEC commands (adb shell) from an Amlogic 905x ARM board (Android 6) to test the functionality. The board is rooted (tested, 'adb root' works) and connected to a TV with CEC capabilities (enabled, tested with video game console too).

First of all I want to clarify if the core functionality is built in, so I guess that if the right CEC command is sent to the right channel, I should notice a change of any kind to the TV set.

I want to test it at a lower abstraction level (sysfs i guess is ok and http://www.cec-o-matic.com/ is pretty straightforward on how to build the command strings) to avoid the complexity of a system library as of this step.

I noticed that some guys had positive results on turning the TV on, by using:

```
#echo 0x40 0x04 > /sys/class/cec/cmd
```

It didn't work on my end.

I think that I might have a different class file allocated for this purpose and I found '/sys/class/amhdmitx/amhdmitx0' which has a lot of endpoints/files that offers IO capabilities.

I got back from the device the details of the TV set connected to (EDID - Extended Display Identification Data), by using:

```
#cat /sys/class/amhdmitx/amhdmitx0/edid
```

That means there has to be a way to send commands to the TV too, like turning the TV on/off, changing source ...

Tried by sending to debug file because there is no cmd file available like in '/sys/class/cec/cmd':

```
#echo 0x40 0x04 > /sys/class/amhdmitx/amhdmitx0/debug
```

Does anyone know how can I do this, to test the sending procedure (device)-->(TV)?

Why there is no activity on the TV when using '/sys/class/cec/cmd'?

Which is the right file to use to send hex data to the TV?

The result of

```
cat /system/build.prop |grep hdmi && ls -l /dev/cec && ls -laht /sys/class/cec/ && settings list global |grep hdmi && echo 0x40 0x04 > /sys/class/cec/cmd && sleep 0.1 && cat /sys/class/cec/dump_reg && sleep 1 && cat /sys/class/cec/dump_reg
```

is

```
ro.sys.hdmiin.enable=true
mbx.hdmiin.switchfull=false
mbx.hdmiin.videolayer=false
ubootenv.var.hdmimode=
ro.hdmi.device_type=4
persist.sys.hdmi.keep_awake=false
crw-rw-rw- root     root     222,   0 2014-12-31 16:00 cec
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 arc_port
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2018-05-08 08:47 cec -> ../../devices/aocec/cec
--w------- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 cmd
-rw-rw-r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 dbg_en
-rw-rw-r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 device_type
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 dump_reg
-rw-rw-r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 fun_cfg
-rw-rw-r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 menu_language
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 osd_name
-rw-rw-r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 physical_addr
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 port_num
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 port_seq
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 port_status
-rw-rw-r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 vendor_id
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2018-05-08 08:47 wake_up
```

Comment: Can you please share the result of: cat /system/build.prop |grep hdmi && ls -l /dev/cec && ls -laht /sys/class/cec/ && settings list global |grep hdmi && echo 0x40 0x04 > /sys/class/cec/cmd && sleep 0.1 && cat /sys/class/cec/dump_reg && sleep 1 && cat /sys/class/cec/dump_reg

Comment: i've edited my question with the info you requested. tks for your help and sorry for the delay

Comment: please confirm that you've added all output cause I'm not seeing the file dump_reg neither the output of it. thanks

Comment: i've got an error at some point saying that ls -h and -t is not recognized and i had to delete them to get that output. basically I dumped everything to a file and copy/paste from there. that's the entire output i got

Comment: @whiletrue i need your help about cec
i had execute that command and having results

Comment: I'm not with this in hands anymore but I can try to help you. Let me know what are the commands, results and your question. You can also post a new question on stackoverflow and point me to there, if you want to write with more detail.

Comment: @whiletrue can u share/suggest something that can help me for how to pass commands from android tv box to tv via hdmi-cec to turn on/off tv.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892639/hdmi-cec-on-android/48082147?noredirect=1#comment114105704_48082147 ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply missing how to write to file? It is

## echo "0x40 0x04" > /sys/class/cec/cmd

That works for me on s905x3 unit.