# Turn off (Stand by) android tv using HDMI CEC command is not working with Amlogic MBOX

Tags: android, android-tv, hdmi-cec

I am trying to turn off my Samsung tv through android app using HDMI CEC for Android I used Amlogic MBOX

1. Samsung Tv HDMI CEC already turned on.
2. Amlogic MBOX HDMI CEC also turned on.

Code snippet how I execute command in Android

```kotlin
fun sudoForResult(vararg strings: String): String? {
    Log.e("TAG", "sudoForResult: executing ")
    var res: String? = ""
    var outputStream: DataOutputStream? = null
    var response: InputStream? = null
    try {
        val su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")
        outputStream = DataOutputStream(su.outputStream)
        response = su.inputStream
        for (s in strings) {
            outputStream.writeBytes("$s\n")
            outputStream.flush()
        }
        outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n")
        outputStream.flush()
        try {
            su.waitFor()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        res = readFully(response)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        outputStream?.close()
        response?.close()
    }
    Log.e("TAG", "sudoForResult: op = \n$res")
    return res
}
```

this command used for enable HDMI CEC in Amlogic MBOX and it's working.

```kotlin
sudoForResult(
    "settings put global hdmi_control_enabled 1",
    "settings put global hdmi_control_auto_wakeup_enabled 1",
    "settings put global hdmi_control_auto_device_off_enabled 1"
)
```

this both command tried but tv is not turn off.

```kotlin
sudoForResult("echo 0x40 0x36 > /sys/class/cec/cmd")
sudoForResult("echo 0xF0 0x36 > /sys/class/cec/cmd")
```

My Amlogic MBOX is already root device.

I am also tried most of answers and comment of the question related Hdmi-cec.

Any one can help regarding this issue?

Some other command with log output if any one can found issue or solution from that

```
1.   sudoForResult(
            "ls -l /dev/cec",
            "ls -l /sys/class/cec/",
            "cat /sys/class/cec/physical_addr",
            "cat /sys/class/cec/device_type",
            "cat /sys/class/cec/vendor_id"
        )
    
Log output :
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 217,   0 2023-07-07 09:05 /dev/cec 
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 arc_port
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 2023-07-07 09:14 cec -> ../../devices/aocec/cec
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 cec_version
--w------- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:19 cmd
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 dbg_en
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 device_type
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 dump_reg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 fun_cfg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 menu_language
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 osd_name
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 physical_addr
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 pin_status
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 port_num
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 port_seq
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 port_status
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 vendor_id
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2023-07-07 09:14 wake_up
1000
4
0


2.  sudoForResult("echo 0xF0 0x36 > /sys/class/cec/cmd && sleep 0.1 && cat /sys/class/cec/dump_reg")

Log output :

TX buffer:
0: 0
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 0
5: 0
6: 0
7: 0
8: 0
9: 0
10: 0
11: 0
12: 0
13: 0
14: 0
15: 0
CEC_TX_MSG_LENGTH: 0
CEC_TX_MSG_CMD: 0
CEC_TX_WRITE_BUF: 0
CEC_TX_CLEAR_BUF: 0
CEC_RX_MSG_CMD: 0
CEC_RX_CLEAR_BUF: 0
CEC_LOGICAL_ADDR0:14
CEC_LOGICAL_ADDR1: 0
CEC_LOGICAL_ADDR2: 0
CEC_LOGICAL_ADDR3: 0
CEC_LOGICAL_ADDR4: 0
CEC_CLOCK_DIV_H: 0
CEC_CLOCK_DIV_L: 0
RX buffer:
0: 0
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 0
5: 0
6: 0
7: 0
8: 0
9: 0
10: 0
11: 0
12: 0
13: 0
14: 0
15: 0
CEC_RX_MSG_LENGTH: 0
CEC_RX_MSG_STATUS: 0
CEC_RX_NUM_MSG: 0
CEC_TX_MSG_STATUS: 0
CEC_TX_NUM_MSG: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this commands

echo "0x40 0x36" > /sys/class/cec/cmd - Turn OFF TV

echo "0x40 0x04" > /sys/class/cec/cmd - Turn ON TV

Comment: `echo "0x40 0x36" > /sys/class/cec/cmd - Turn OFF TV`. <br/>
@mageshgopal. <br/>
I am already use that command also that's already mention in question.<br/>  
But didn't work. <br/>
`sudoForResult("echo 0x40 0x36 > /sys/class/cec/cmd")`

Comment: Oh sorry. But this is working for me. Im also using Amlogic S905Y4,S905C3 devices it is working perfectly. 

Can you share output of : "dumpsys hdmi_control"

It looks like below , You can see all the information. Le

    [S] time=2024-02-27 10:43:39 message=<Give Device Power Status> 40:8F
    [S] time=2024-02-27 10:43:39 message=<Report Physical Address> 4F:84:10:00:04
    [S] time=2024-02-27 10:43:39 message=<Device Vendor Id> 4F:87:FF:FF:FF
    [S] time=2024-02-27 10:43:39 message=<Give Device Vendor Id> 40:8C